# Getting data sets from separate text file

Tags: c++, void

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with my problem. So the program I am working on tries to calculate the flight distance of non stop flights compared to flights that stop in one city other than the desired destination. So far I have gotten the first two data set to pop up but when I try to get the third data set, I get the second set of cities. I am using void functions and this is my first program with void functions. My code for the part where I get the date from is:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void readFile(int choice, double &begLat, double &begLon, string &begCity,
    double &midLat, double &midLon, string &midCity,
    double &endLat, double &endLon, string &endCity);
void intro();
void askDataSet(int &selection);
int dist(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2);

//--------------------------------------------------

int main()
{

    intro();

    double begLat, begLon, midLat, midLon, endLat, endLon;
    string begCity, midCity, endCity;
    int choice;
    askDataSet(choice);

    readFile(choice, begLat, begLon, begCity, midLat, midLon, midCity, endLat, endLon, endCity);
    cout << "The First City at coordinates " << begLat << " and " << begLon << " is:  " << begCity << endl;
    cout << "The Second City at coordinates " << midLat << " and " << midLon << " is:  " << midCity << endl;
    cout << "The Third City at coordinates " << endLat << " and " << endLon << " is:  " << endCity << endl;

    int leg1, leg2, nonstop;
    leg1 = dist(begLat, begLon, midLat, midLon);
    leg2 = dist(midLat, midLon, endLat, endLon);
    nonstop = dist(begLat, begLon, endLat, endLon);
    cout << "The legs are " << leg1 << " and " << leg2 << endl;
    cout << "Nonstop is " << nonstop << endl;

    cout << "It is " << leg2 + leg1 - nonstop << " fewer miles for non-stop" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void readFile(int choice, double &begLat, double &begLon, string &begCity,
    double &midLat, double &midLon, string &midCity,
    double &endLat, double &endLon, string &endCity)
{
    ifstream dataIn;
    dataIn.open("cities.txt");
    if (dataIn.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error.  File does not exist. " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        dataIn >> begLat;
        dataIn >> begLon;
        dataIn.get();
        getline(dataIn, begCity);
        dataIn >> midLat;
        dataIn >> midLon;
        dataIn.get();
        getline(dataIn, midCity);
        dataIn >> endLat;
        dataIn >> endLon;
        dataIn.get();
        getline(dataIn, endCity);
    }

    string trash;
    if (choice == 2)
    {
        getline(dataIn, trash);
        getline(dataIn, trash);
        getline(dataIn, trash);
        getline(dataIn, trash);
        getline(dataIn, trash);
        getline(dataIn, trash);
        getline(dataIn, trash);

        dataIn >> begLat;
        dataIn >> begLon;
        dataIn.get();
        getline(dataIn, begCity);
        dataIn >> midLat;
        dataIn >> midLon;
        dataIn.get();
        getline(dataIn, midCity);
        dataIn >> endLat;
        dataIn >> endLon;
        dataIn.get();
        getline(dataIn, endCity);
    }


    if (choice == 3)
    {
        getline(dataIn, trash);
        getline(dataIn, trash);
        getline(dataIn, trash);
        getline(dataIn, trash);
        getline(dataIn, trash);
        getline(dataIn, trash);
        getline(dataIn, trash);

        dataIn >> begLat;
        dataIn >> begLon;
        dataIn.get();
        getline(dataIn, begCity);
        dataIn >> midLat;
        dataIn >> midLon;
        dataIn.get();
        getline(dataIn, midCity);
        dataIn >> endLat;
        dataIn >> endLon;
        dataIn.get();
        getline(dataIn, endCity);

    }
}

void intro()
{
    cout << "In this lab we will try to figure out how much shorter it is to fly non-stop compared to one-stop." << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

void askDataSet(int &selection)
{
    cout << "Do you wish to use dataset 1, 2, or 3? ";
    cin >> selection;
    while (selection < 1 || selection > 3)
    {
        cout << "The only valid choices are 1-3. Please re-enter";
        cin >> selection;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int dist(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
{
    double diffLat, diffLon, hyp;
    diffLat = (lat1 - lat2) * 69;
    diffLon = (lon1 - lon2) * 53;
    hyp = sqrt(diffLat * diffLat + diffLon * diffLon);
    return static_cast<int>(hyp);
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to indent it properly. I am having trouble with the dataIn >> begLat part. I tried putting a bunch of those statements in and also put in getLine( data, trash ) to replace one set of data with the other. I am using void functions and this is my first program with void functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're reading choice #3 the same as you read choice #2. So basically you're reading the same data set. In choice #3, you need to skip more data lines before actually reading data. So per your method (which seems a bit naive) there should be twice as many getline(dataIn, trash); as in choice #2.

Comment: Oh okay. Sorry but that's the only way I know right now. Could you tell me a better way so that I don't have to keep writing those lines over and over again?

Comment: For starters you could use a for or while loop to skip over the unneeded data. You could also put it in a function and call it once or twice, depending on the user's choice. Another alternative is to always read the sets into an array, and then accessing the needed array item according to the choice. Maybe ifstream also has functions that can help you make it more effective, but I haven't really looked into it. Good luck.

Comment: Arrays was easier. Thanks for telling me. I'm not that great at programming as I just started.